# Windows 10 Station Accessible by IP but not by Name on same subnet

Tags: windows-10

We have some Win10 systems in Active Directory, and some systems (not used by people, just slave stations for running background processes) that are NOT in Active Directory.

I notice that the systems in AD can be resolved by name, but the stations NOT in AD cannot be resolved by name. What stumps me more is that the non-AD systems use DHCP to get their IP from the DNS on AD. I thought that getting an IP from an AD-integrated DHCP would make the system resolveable by name?

I believe the non-AD systems resolved fine by name until they were renamed.

The non-AD systems are part of "workgroup" (the Windows default).

How do I get these non-AD systems resolved by name?

**AD system**: Can resolve all AD systems by name, cannot resolve non-AD systems by name.

**Non-AD systems**: Can resolve all AD systems by name, cannot resolve non-AD systems by name.

I thought that netbios over TCPIP would, in event that DNS resolution fails, put out a broadcast packet to discover the IP of a named system. What should I do to resolve?

Comment: if the computers are not in AD but you want them to resolve by DNS query on the AD DNS zone, then you will have to assign them static IPs (or use DHCP reservations) and then manually create DNS entries for those hosts. NBT will only attempt to resolve a name via broadcast for NetBIOS services like File and Print Sharing. they will not work for Ping, or a web browser, or any other pure-IP based mechanism.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks. I updated the OP to mention the DHCP angle

Comment: No, computers that are not on the domain will not register their IP address with DNS automatically. Note that the client registers with the DNS server (using `ipconfig /registerdns`), not the DHCP server. You can tell the client to register its DNS, but without domain membership, it is my understanding that it will not be allowed to register. so make sure they have static(or reserved) IPs, and then manually configure DNS entries for them.